# Python: Convert raw_input() into binary then use it in a function

Tags: python

I'm working on a function which checks if the fourth bit from the right in a binary is active.

Here is my code:

```
bit2= 0b1000
entry = bin(int(raw_input("Type a number : ")))


def verifier_bit4(entry):
    if entry & bit2 > 0 :
        return "on"
    else:
        return "off"

print verifier_bit4(entry)
```

It was working fine if defined myself the value of entry as a binary (example: entry = 0b1001 ).

However I decided to make it more user friendly and to ask the user to enter a number with `raw_input()`.

Then I got this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 11, in 
>      File "python", line 6, in verifier_bit4 TypeError: 
>   unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

I checked the variable 'entry' and it is indeed a binary, so I don't understand why my code isn't working.

Anybody help? :)

Comment: "I checked the variable 'entry' and it is indeed a binary". But Python doesn't have a "binary" type. I'm pretty sure `bin` returns a string.

Comment: @Kevin  Python's binary type is arguably `bool`  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Actually `bin` returns a string representation of a number, in binary:

```
>>> bin(123)
'0b1111011'
```

You can just remove that `bin` call, since you probably want to use the `int` here anyway.

Comment: Thank you @wim! I didn't know bin() returned a string

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a binary for bitwise operands :

```
>>> 32 & 8
0
>>> 12 & 8
8
```

They're defined on integers :

```
bit2 = 0b1000
entry = int(raw_input("Type a number : "))


def verifier_bit4(entry):
    if entry & bit2 > 0 :
        return "on"
    else:
        return "off"

print verifier_bit4(entry)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to let the user enter numbers in the binary representation, you must tell `int()` about it:

```
entry = int(raw_input("Type a number : "), 2)
```

Then input like `0b0010` is possible.